# SED multiline search and replace error

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sed

I have an XML file (config.xml) as below.

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
   <triggers>
    <com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger plugin="github@1.29.2">
      <spec/>
    </com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger>
   </triggers>
   <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  </project>
```

I want to replace the triggers block with only `<triggers/>`. But when I use SED to do it, I get this error:

`sed: 1: "/<triggers>/{:a;N;/<\/t ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`

Command:

`sed -i '.bak' '/<triggers>/{:a;N;/<\/triggers>/!ba;N;s/.*\n/<triggers\/>\n/};p' config.yml`

I want you to know what am I missing here and how to get the desired outcome?

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
<blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
</triggers>
<concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
</project>
```

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: You mean you actually want to produce invalid XML output, containing an end tag with no matching start tag? That's a pretty weird requirement...

Comment: This should work in your case, but **I don't recommend it**: `sed -e '/<triggers>/,/<\/triggers>/{/<\/triggers>/{i \ \ </triggers>' -e '};d}' file.xml`

Comment: I have edit the question, realized it later. Modified it to get valid XML. When I run: 

    `sed -e '/<triggers>/,/<\/triggers>/{/<\/triggers>/{i \ \ <triggers\/>' -e '};d}' file.xml`

Output:

    `sed: 1: "/<triggers>/,/<\/trigge ...": extra characters after \ at the end of i command`

Answer (score 2):

With this valid XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers>
    <com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger plugin="github@1.29.2">
      <spec/>
    </com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger>
  </triggers>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
</root>
```

With this command:

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl --update "//triggers" --value ""
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
</root>
```

If you want to edit file inplace, add option -L.

---

See: `xmlstarlet edit --help`

Comment: I get this strange error with inline option:


`xmlstarlet edit -L --update "//triggers" --value "" config.xml
config.xml:1.20: Unsupported version '1.1'
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

It doesn't seem to like the XML version.

Comment: It looks like your xmlstarlet does not support XML version 1.1.

Comment: And the other problem I am facing is, production servers don't have `xmlstarlet` installed. That is the reason I am stuck with SED. I went through a lot of questions here before posting mine.